# TypeScript: Union as template parameter iterated in extends

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type SomeA<T> = T extends string ? true : false;
type SomeB    = string | number extends string ? true : false;

type A = SomeA<string | number> // resolves to boolean
type B = SomeB // resolves to false
```

In the above why does `A` resolve to `boolean` but `B` resolves to `false` even though after passing `string | number` to `SomeA` it looks like it'd be equivalent of `SomeB`?

Comment: `SomeA<T>` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) while `SomeB` is not

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz. I wasn't aware of this. However, would you know if I wanted to force `SomeA<string | number>`'s behavior to be that of `SomeB`, how would I do that?

Comment: You would need to "clothe" the naked type parameter, the easiest way being with a one-tuple: `type A<T> = [T] extends [string] ? true : false`

Comment: Let me know if either of those two other answers does not suffice; otherwise I will likely mark this as a duplicate of those.  Good luck!

Comment: They help me. Thank you :) Can be marked duplicate.